# getting java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error while calling a SOAP web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a SOAP webservice in android, but getting this exception:

java.net.ConnectException: - Connection refused

But I am able to hit that webservice wsdl through desktop, its working fine .
Does anyone knows what can be the reason for this exception.

Comment: is the webservice  running on localhost?

Comment: can you put some logcat?

Comment: @Metahead1247... no it has a URL which I am able to hit through Internet Browser...

Comment: paste your  namespace , method name ,soap action and SOAP_ADDRESS

Comment: 09-12 12:48:46.171: W/System.err(7833): java.net.ConnectException: - Connection refused
09-12 12:48:46.171: W/System.err(7833):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
09-12 12:48:46.179: W/System.err(7833):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
09-12 12:48:46.179: W/System.err(7833):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002)
09-12 12:48:46.179: W/System.err(7833):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)

Comment: @Metalhead1247 , namespace, method name, soap action, all are correct because when I hosted that webservice on local intranet it was working fine, I was able to hit that through android code, but when it was shifted to internet server, then it started giving this error.

Comment: Do not make loops! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948769/connection-refused-when-calling-soap-webservice-using-android if this isn't your problem, try to be more specific about what the heck you are doing. We are guessing here...

Comment: may be its your `proxy` thats blocking the connection.

Comment: @androidDev have you changed the SOAP_ADDRESS and Namespace in your android code after shifting it to server?

Comment: @SajanChandran proxy cannot be the problem because I am hitting that webservice through device's 3G connection///

Comment: @androidDev no your internet browser uses a proxy, if its the case, then from your code when you try to connect, you need to provide the proxy details via code.

Comment: @androidDev when you host your webservice on the internet server your SOAP_ADDRESS and Namespace changes

Comment: @Metalhead1247 no its same.. eveything except the URL is same

Comment: @androidDev the url is the SOAP_ADDRESS have you changed that?

Comment: @Metalhead1247 yes... only the IP Address in the URL is changed, rest all is same

Comment: @androidDev paste code in your question

Comment: SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
     SoapEnvelope.VER10);
   envelope.dotNet = true;
   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
   envelope.implicitTypes = false;HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(url);androidHttpTransportSE.debug=true;
    androidHttpTransportSE.call(wsAction, envelope);

Comment: Have you defined proper permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes :)...................

Comment: Can you paste  the url you used in your code?

Comment: @Metalhead1247.. I succeeded in making connection with that URL, but getting NULL POINTER Exception now,,sorry it wont be possible for me to paste that URL

Comment: @androidDev post your logcat