# Android : Calling a webservice using ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, webservice-client, android-ksoap2

I have created a webservice to perform addition. I have created a Android app to consume that webservice and display the output in TextView. Please find the WSDL below and the code

***WSDL***

```
<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:soapjms="http://www.w3.org/2010/soapjms/"
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8080/Monish/TestWebservice"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"name="TestWebservice"
targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/Monish/TestWebservice">
<wsdl:types>
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8080/Monish/TestWebservice"
 targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/Monish/TestWebservice">
   <xsd:element name="myTest" type="tns:myTest"/>
   <xsd:element name="myTestResponse" type="tns:myTestResponse"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="myTest">
   <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="a" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="b" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="myTestResponse">
 <xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="output" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
 <wsdl:message name="TestWebservice_PortType_myTestResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:myTestResponse"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="TestWebservice_PortType_myTest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:myTest"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="TestWebservice_PortType">
<wsdl:operation name="myTest">
<wsdl:input message="tns:TestWebservice_PortType_myTest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:TestWebservice_PortType_myTestResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="Monish_TestWebservice_Binder" type="tns:TestWebservice_PortType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="myTest">
<soap:operation soapAction="Monish_TestWebservice_Binder_myTest" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
 <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="TestWebservice">
<wsdl:port name="Monish_TestWebservice_Port" binding="tns:Monish_TestWebservice_Binder">
 <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws/Monish:TestWebservice/Monish_TestWebservice_Port"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Code**

```
package com.webservice;

public class WebServiceDemoActivity extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost:8080/Monish/TestWebservice/"; 
private final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/Monish/TestWebservice?WSDL";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "Monish_TestWebservice_Binder_myTest";  
private final String METHOD_NAME = "myTest"; 

    ArrayList<Guard> guardList=new ArrayList<Guard>();
    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo propInfo=new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo.type=PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                    //adding parameters
        request.addProperty("a", 10);
        request.addProperty("b", 15);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = false;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();


            Log.e("Object response", response.toString());
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Output: "+response.toString());
            setContentView(tv);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.webservice"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.webservice.WebServiceDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I feel the webservice is not getting called. I have used the text view to display the output. Please help me out with this. Im not getting any output :(

Even after adding
     Log.e("Object response", response.toString());

I'm not able to see anything in LogCat!

many thanks!!

Comment: i assume your android and server are on same machine (because you are using localhost) ? if yes, localhost will be considered android's emulator, you should use IP 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost. SEE http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Answer (score 0):

URL is http://**localhost:8080**/Monish/TestWebservice?WSDL
This means that web-service is listening on android device?

Comment: yes! But the webserive is not getting called i believe. I'm not able to see the response in LogCat either

Comment: In ane case you should use the service URL (location in WSDL), not the WSDL URL.

Comment: @SandroProxysupport - The Webservice was created using webMethods(java platform). Infact, will it matter in which technology the WS was created? i'm not sure kindly clarify.

Comment: I'm just making sure that you are not making this mistake :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948769/connection-refused-when-calling-soap-webservice-using-android what else can be wrong ... checking that on android device is really service waiting on port 8080 with netstat from adb shell, using some other android app making same request http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/ProjectsUsingKsoap2Android