# How to properly request web service from android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am trying to consume a web service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "SayHelloService")
public class SayHelloService {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        //return "Hello " + txt + " !";
        return "Application submitted successfully!";
    }
}
```

from an android app:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    String editText = "me";
    String displayText; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ws_response_string);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
               public void onClick(View v) 
               {               
                   AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                   task.execute();
               }
           });
    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
        {                
            //Invoke webservice                
            displayText = WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(editText,"hello");
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            tv.setText(displayText);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
}
```

with these properties:

```
public class WebService 
{
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://example.vnsgbt.org/";
    private static String URL = "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWebService/SayHelloService?wsdl";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://example.vnsgbt.org/";
    public static String invokeHelloWorldWS(String name, String webMethName) 
    {
        String resTxt = null;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
        PropertyInfo sayHelloPI = new PropertyInfo();
        sayHelloPI.setName("name");
        sayHelloPI.setValue(name);
        sayHelloPI.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(sayHelloPI);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try 
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resTxt = response.toString();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //resTxt = "Error occurred";
            resTxt = e.getMessage();
        } 
        return resTxt;
    }
}
```

My wsdl looks like:

```
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://example.vnsgbt.org/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWebService/SayHelloService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="hello">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:hello"/>
</message>
<message name="helloResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="SayHelloService">
<operation name="hello">
<input wsam:Action="http://example.vnsgbt.org/SayHelloService/helloRequest" message="tns:hello"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://example.vnsgbt.org/SayHelloService/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="SayHelloServicePortBinding" type="tns:SayHelloService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="hello">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="SayHelloService">
<port name="SayHelloServicePort" binding="tns:SayHelloServicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWebService/SayHelloService"/>
</port>
</service>
```

I keep getting error message from exception instead of successful message from the web service. 
I'm guessing there's something wrong with the way I set SOAP properties. 
Could you please show what the problem is?
Updated: The error message I got is: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: If you are writing the server and the client I strongly recommend using rest and json, since soap and xml are bulky and slow to process for mobile devices and slow to transmit on mobile networks.

Comment: Could you post the error messages you get?  They are probably an indicator as to the problem.

Comment: I am aware of the simplicity of REST. I would definitely prefer REST. However, I am also trying to learn SOAP which result in this exercise. The error message I got from exception is: ECONNREFUSED (connection refused).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem is because I was using localhost on android emulator.

This is explained in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866889/1971025.

Thanks everyones for your effort!