# Mono. Web API Service is returning 0 - when invoking form outside

Tags: c#, web-services, nginx, mono

My Web API Service is running on Linux Ubuntu with Mono and Nginx.

When I test my API from localhost it works perfectly and writes every request into log file, but if I invoke a method from outside environment (from other IP) the response is:

`The web service returned the following result:`

 `0 -`

also it's not writing any error log so I could investigate the problem.

Here is my method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Test(string strXML)
{
    string strMessage = "";
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        xdoc.LoadXml(strXML);

        XmlNode xContent = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("content")[0];
        strMessage = xContent.InnerText;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return strMessage;
}
```

What can you suggest guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the answer by marc.d from this post:

[Connection refused when calling SOAP Webservice using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948769/connection-refused-when-calling-soap-webservice-using-android)

it helped in my case.